# How to Manually Write to Console G++ Linux W/O printf / cout?

Tags: c++, linux, console, g++, buffer

I want to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW8skO7MFYw&t=357s tutorial, but at one point the author manually allocates the console to be more efficient. He uses what looks like Windows specific instructions, but I want to achieve the same thing on Linux. I am on Debian 9.8 and using g++6.3. This is the code I want to duplicate on my Linux end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int nScreenWidth = 120;         
int nScreenHeight = 40; 

wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];
HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
```

I already tried finding a solution to this and I couldn't find anything. Thanks I appreciate the help

Comment: You may want to use ncurses. https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just want to use the most optimal way because the tutorial consists of writing to the console very often. I am also a Linux newb as you can probably tell. What would be the most efficient way? Could I just go ahead and use printf? Or as drescherjm suggests, use ncurses?

Comment: What sort of app would need to write to the console so often that there would be performance issues? Are you planning a console-like game?

Comment: Yes the tutorial I am following as a 3D game which all takes place in the console. I could simply switch over to Windows and follow along, but I would like to learn more about Linux simultaneously. I want to achieve similar results as he does by manually allocating the console.

Comment: Are you doing graphics or text? If you're writing text, `ncurses` should be fast enough. People created text-mode games on Unix computers 20 years ago and the speed was fast enough then. Computers are thousands of times faster now.